# Change Return type of Overridden Methods?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

The below is the "ControllerAdvice" and it acts as the Global Exception Handler for **Multiple MicroServices**.

```
// Custom Exception Handler
@ExceptionHandler(value = CustomException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> customException(CustomException ex) {
    ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse(ex.getErrorDescription(), ex.getErrorMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(error, ex.getStatus());
}

@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public ErrorResponse globalException(Exception ex) {
        
    return new ErrorMessage("INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR", "500");    
}
```

Now for One of my MicroService, I need to customize the Error Response coming from the above Exception Handler i.e I need to Wrap the "ErrorResponse" coming from the Global Exception Handler under another Object called "ErrorResponseWrapper"

```
class ErrorResponseWrapper extends ErrorResponse {

   String type;

   // getter & setters
}
```

Now in My Microservice where I need to Customise the error Response, I am just Overriding the GlobalExceptionHandler methods

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ControllerException extends GlobalExceptionHandler {

    // This Works FINE...
    @Override
    public ErrorResponseWrapper globalException(Exception ex) {
        // 
        ErrorResponse error = super.globalException(ex);

        // New Response Wrapper
        ErrorResponseWrapper wrapper = new ResponseWrapper();
        wrapper.setType("SOMETHING");
        
        return wrapper;
    }

//Issue is here:- 
//   I get Compilation Error: ReturnType is Not Compatible with the GlobalException return type.

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseWrapper> customException(CustomException ex) {
        
        ErrorResponse error = super.customException(ex).getBody();

        // New Response Wrapper
        ErrorResponseWrapper wrapper = new ResponseWrapper();
        wrapper.setType("SOMETHING");
    
        return new ResponseEntity<>(wrapper,ex.getStatus());
}

}
```

It works fine with the First Overridden method, why is it different from the ResponseEntity? Is there anything I am doing wrong, or how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is generics, and that they are invariant by default, which trips up loads of people and may not immediately come across as logical or correct (but, it is - keep reading).

There are these 3 concepts, called **invariant** / **covariant** / **contravariant**.

### Covariant

covariant means that a subtype of a thing is just as good as the thing.

Java basic typing is covariant. Here:

```
Integer x = 5;
Number n = x; // This compiles and runs just great.
```

Note how the type of `x` is Integer, which is a **subtype** of `Number`, and yet that is fine here. That's because covariance is applied here.

### Contravariance

Contravariance is the inverse: A supertype is a fair standin. This is actually part of java: When overriding methods, you can use supertypes for parameters and that is fine. This compiles:

```
public class Parent {
    public void foo(String x) {}
}
```

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    @Override public void foo(Object x) {}
}
```

The reason this is okay should be obvious: Because common sense: All strings are also objects therefore the `foo` method that Child defines can handle all possible cases of invoking `foo` whenever an instance of `Child` is treated as if its a `Parent`. It can handle all of these (that'd be when `x` is a `String`), and more to boot.

### Generics and variance

Generics is **invariant** by default. That's a head twister! Let's check it out:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Object> list2 = list1; // DOES NOT COMPILE!!
```

That's bizarre, isn't it? But it makes sense! After all, if the above code works, `list1` and `list2` are both pointing at the same actual list; therefore if you make a change to this one list via the `list1` ref, you'd be able to see the change when using the `list2` ref. But, therein lies the problem: I can run `list2.add(new Object())`, but that would mean that `list1.get()` returns an `Object` and not a `String`.

That is why generics are invariant: Because the universe works that way.

This applies everywhere. Thus, we get to the crux of your problem here:

**`ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseWrapper>` is not a subtype of `ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>`!**

Fortunately, generics are quite flexible. You can have covariance and even contravariance if you want it; just, ask for it. Here, now it works fine:

```
public class Parent {
    public ResponseEntity<? extends ErrorResponse> foo() {}
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    @Override public ResponseEntity<? extends ErrorResponseWrapper> foo() {}
}
```

That does work fine. `? extends` is java-ese for: I want generics, but covariant. The compiler will then help you out and prevent you from breaking the world. Let's try it:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends Object> list2 = list1; // now it compiles!
list2.add(new Object()); // but this does not!
```

Calling `.add()` on any `List<? extends Y>` where Y can be anything you please *does not compile*, unless you pass a literal `null` and only because `null` is every type. That is on purpose - it lets you assign that list-of-strings to the ref.

### The fix

Go back to the original type and update the return type. If you can't do that, there is nothing you can do here.

Answer (score 1):

While defining the CustomHandler you need to use

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = CustomException.class)
public ResponseEntity<? extends ErrorResponse> customException(CustomException ex) {
    ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse(ex.getErrorDescription(), ex.getErrorMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(error, ex.getStatus());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your original `customException` method:

```java
@ExceptionHandler(value = CustomException.class)
public ResponseEntity<T extends ErrorResponse> customException(CustomException ex) {
    ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse(ex.getErrorDescription(), ex.getErrorMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(error, ex.getStatus());
}
```

Comment: Generics serve to link things, for the benefit of compiler analysis. __That is all they are good for__, given that generics are erased at runtime. It lets the compiler know that expressions/types occuring in 2 or more places are linked together. This also means that if you declare a type var and use it less than 2 times, __that is a hack, or useless__. Therefore, this code is a style faux pas so bad, it ought to be flagged down by any style guide as broken. Most likely you meant `ResponseEntity<? extends ErrorResponse>`, but without an explanation of why this answer remains unsuitable.

Comment: Hi @rzwitserloot, thanks for pointing that out! I've edited my answer.